# php session upload progress

Tags: php, session, upload, progress

I need your help. I've been trying detect upload progress for three days. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I need someone's help.

That's what I do:

**The structure:**
1 html form
2 jQuery
3 upload.php
4 progress.php

**Html form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm">
<input type="hidden" name="<? echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="bar" id="systemName">
<input type="file" name="video[]" accept="video/avi, video/mp4, video/flv, video/mov, video/mkv, video/ogg, video/wmv, video/webm, video/ogv">
<button type="button" name="send" class="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.uploadBtn').on('click', function(){

var formData = $('#uploadForm').serializefiles();

$.ajax({ // let's send a file to upload.php
url: 'upload.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
data: formData,
async: true,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function(json){
if(typeof json.success !== 'undefined'){
$.jGrowl(json.success);
} else if(typeof json.error !== 'undefined'){
$.jGrowl(json.error);
}
},
error: function(json, jqXHR, status, errorThrown, exception){
return $.jGrowl('ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR, json);
}
});


getting_progress(); // function below

});




function getting_progress(){ // let's send query to progress.php and check session array
var interval_id = setInterval(function () {

$.ajax({
url: 'progress.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
data:($('#systemName')),
success: function(json){
if(typeof json.success !== 'undefined'){
$.jGrowl(json.success);
clearInterval(interval_id);
} else if(typeof json.error !== 'undefined'){
$.jGrowl(json.error);
}
},
error: function(json, jqXHR, status, errorThrown, exception){
return $.jGrowl('ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR, json);
}
});
}, 1000); // every second
}
```

**progress.php**

```
<?

session_start(); // let's start session

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix").$_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")]; // upload_progress_bar

$ssn = json_encode($_SESSION);

if(isset($_SESSION[$key])){
echo json_encode(['success' => 'yes'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit();
}

else{
echo json_encode(['error' => 'no '.$ssn], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit();
}
```

The problem is that I get 'no []' every time. If I `print_r $_SESSION` it is empty.  Could someone help me to solve this problem?

**My php info**

```
v 7.3
output_buffering Off
session.upload_progress.cleanup Off
session.upload_progress.enabled On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_
```

My web site **doesn't** run FastCGI

Comment: There is a lot to digest, but an initial observation is that **getting_progress();** will be ran BEFORE the upload.php is completed. You can try moving it into the success function.

Comment: @imvain2 Well, why do you say that getting_progress(); should run after upload is completed? In this case there won't be any progress in $_SESSION.